# a question about linear algebra and matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Given a  $n\times n$ matrix A,and the matrix's characteristic polynomial is $|\alpha I-A|=(\alpha-a_{1})^{r_{1}}(\alpha-a_{2})^{r_{2}}...(\alpha-a_{p})^{r_{p}}$,and $r_1+r_2+...r_p=n$. Then,as for any eigenvalue $a_i$,do we have $$ rank(A-a_i I)=rank((A-a_iI )^m$$?( m is any positive integer and 1<=i<=p)

That's really confusing me,can someone tell me whether it is true or not? How to prove it?need some help

Comment: No, take any Jordan block of size two or larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this not true. Take
$$A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has eigenvalue 1, its characteristic polynomial is $\det (A-\lambda I) = (\lambda-1)^2$.

You have
$$A - I = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
which has rank 1, but
$$(A-I)^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
has rank zero.